# Calling onResume method from onTabSelected method

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

Is there any way to call `onResume` method of a fragment from the `onTabSelected` method? Actually, I'm able to get the fragment on selecting the tab but it is not getting refreshed. It should get refreshed as I have called an Async Task method from my `onResume`, which updates my view.

Is there any alternative to what I am trying to do?

```
public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, android.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
    Log.d("tab selected","tab selected");
    viewpager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
}
```

Comment: Do not call lifecycle methods manually, it's a recipe for disaster. You have to rethink our Activity.

Comment: In my application, I want to make 3 tabs. Every time I click on a different tab, I should get refreshed data. Without ViewPager, I am getting refreshed data but no swipe feature. Can you advise what can I use here to do what I am doing ?

Comment: Do not use native tabs, use Square's ViewPagerIndicator instead.